# \charscalexN not working on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

Images:

- [Shown on my program's RichTextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWnfp.png)
- [Shown on my program's MessageBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn5A7.png)
- [Shown on Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/148oX.png)
- [Shown on Wordpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NeCh.png)

My code:

```
private void BtnSetContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fn = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\보통 글자.rtf";
    string towrite = "";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn);
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        towrite += sr.ReadLine() + " ";
    }
    sr.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(towrite);
    RTBMainText.Rtf = towrite;
}
```

I want to show 200% stretched text (e.g. `{\charscalex200 Stretched}`) on a `RichTextBox` but this keyword seems to be ignored so `charscalex`ed texts are shown without changes.

Is there any solution, vanilla or with some extra libraries, to show stretched texts?

Comment: You don't need any of that code. The RichTextBox control has a LoadFile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the latest version of the RichText library.  Create your own RichTextBox control and override the CreateParams property:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class RichBox : RichTextBox {

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
      var cp = base.CreateParams;
      if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero) {
        cp.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
      }
      return cp;
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Rebuild your solution and use this control in place of the standard RichTextBox control.

Also, you can just use the LoadFile method:

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\보통 글자.rtf");
```

Comment: The .Net `RichTextBox` class is (probably) already `RICHEDIT50W`. Anyway, there's no guarantee that it will process that command (I'ld say it doesn't). But it can size it with `\fsN`, where N is the font height in pixels.

Comment: @Jimi It's probably not.  I tested this and duplicated the problem the OP was having, and this resolved it for me.

Comment: You mean, it scales the Font? As I said, there's no guarantee, In Windows 7, it will not (as Wordpad doesn't). But the class in .Net 4.7 is already `RICHEDIT50W`.

Comment: @Jimi Yes (I updated with an image).  This was on .net 4.6.1.  I'm on Windows 10.  Windows 7 is obsolete now, I believe.

Comment: Probably. Just some informations the OP might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. At first moment the design view didn't show the white box to me, but a minute after rebuild it was also solved.